# zipcode checker with iframe in combination with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, joomla2.5

I have a problem with my site, it's based on Joomla 2.5.16
I will try to explain my problem as good as possible.

On my site i have a zipcode checker, were people can check the availability of fiber to the home.
The zipcode checker works with a iframe, in combination with a javascript code that i put in the header.

The Javascript code determines the height of the iframe. as you can see at [www.nederlandkiestvoorglasvezel.nl/glasvezel-vergelijken](http://www.nederlandkiestvoorglasvezel.nl/glasvezel-vergelijken) the height of the iframe is wrong. it seems like something be overwritten the javascriptcode.

Cause when i test the iframe and the javascriptcode outside Joomla, de zipcode checker works fine. you can see it here: http://www.nederlandkiestvoorglasvezel.nl/iframeTest.htm

However, seem to have received to be erroneous data, yet overwritten the same code in your Joomla site the correct value, I see no reason after another everything after passing the following: 
Parent reveived message!: 440

So I hope someone can tell whats the problem, i have tried several opties and got help from my hosting but we can't fix it.

Regards,

Rutger

Comment: as well as posible, as WELL as posible! sorry, that was bugging me :P

Comment: it looks like the code is getting confused with the other iFrames on the page (from the social plugins) and the event is not being raised on your iFrame

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's as silly as this. Look at the height you've set in the iframe with something like firebug. You'll notice that the height property is set to `{"s":"__cb","f":"oauth2relay368429625","c":0,"a":[40,false],"t":"852486603","l":false,"g":true,"r":"oauth2relay368429625"}px`.

You should probably fix that, and then it'll work :)

Edit - more details. This chunk of code is causing it:

```
// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
console.log('parent received message!: ',e.data);
document.getElementById('internetdealerframe').height = e.data + 'px';
},false);
```

Since you're passing around more than just a number, the entire string is being used as a height.

Edit #2

It doesn't look like you're actually passing a valid height anywhere in those postMessage calls - The first one that has any kind of 'height' in it contains the following: `!_{"s":"/I0_1387279282212::_renderstart","f":"I0_1387279282212","r":"I0_1387279282212","t":"24007401","a":[{"height":20,"width":90,"title":"+1"}],"g":false}`. And I'm thinking that you don't actually want the iframe to be 20 pixels high.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont get it,

Cause at my test iframe, outside Joomla, de height works.. as you can see at, http://www.nederlandkiestvoorglasvezel.nl/iframeTest.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but i dont get it,

Cause at my test iframe, outside Joomla, de height works.. as you can see at, http://www.nederlandkiestvoorglasvezel.nl/iframeTest.htm